# Australian Tree Identification - maybe pine?

Tags: species-identification, trees

Can you help identify this species?

[image: Picture of tree to ID]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[(Link to imgur album with all images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brhel.jpg)

It was growing next to the Yarra River (maybe 10 meters from the bank) in Melbourne. At first I thought it was a type of pine however [this page](http://www.eattheweeds.com/australian-pine/) says Australian pines at not actually true pines. It does look much like some of the images of [Australian Pine Casuarina equisetifolia](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Casuarina+equisetifolia&tbm=isch)

However the [Wikipedia page for Casuarina equisetifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casuarina_equisetifolia) says there are 2 subspecies, equisetifolia and incana. Equisetifolia is only found in Southeast Asia & northern Australia so that rules that one out. Incana is found on the east coast of Australia (eastern Queensland, New South Wales) - could it also be found as far down south as Melbourne?

I've also compared it against all the pines on [this site](http://www.allcreativedesigns.com.au/pages/galltrees.html) as it specifically shows Australian species.

From there I thought it looks a bit like a [Port Jackson Cypress Pine Callitris rhomboidea](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Port+Jackson+Cypress+Pine+Callitris+rhomboidea&tbm=isch) but the needles look longer and narrower.

I think it also looks a little like a [Narrow Leaved Wattle Acacia linearifolia](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Narrow+Leaved+Wattle+Acacia+linearifolia&tbm=isch) if you ignore the yellow flowers.

I'm carving a spoon out of some of it's wood so would like to know for sure what species it actually is. Any help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I went back to the tree to get some more photos but the whole tree had fallen in the river!

[image]

I did get a branch off it however to get a close up of the nodes / internodes but I could not find any seeds or cones.

[image]

**FINAL UPDATE:**

I've tried to get a close up of the apical portion (the top bit right?). My twig sample has started to dry up a bit so this is the best I could get.

[image]
[image]

**ONE MORE UPDATE**

Due to my last pictures being rather fuzzy I got out the DSLR and the tripod. These photos are very high res and around 8mb each so may take a while to load...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You've correctly observed, it looks like *Casuarina* sp (an angiosperm) and some member of cupressaceae (*Callitris* , *Juniperus* etc) of conifer group of gymnosperm. Like those plants, in OP's specimen, green, narrow things are seemingly stem-branches (and not leaves at all) because they're clearly differentiated into nodes and internodes.

Comment: Could you find any reproductive structures like cones/ seeds etc? Also it would do help if you add a close-up of the nodal region of green axes (likely there is some small leaf or scale-like thing) and the internodes. Is the internode-axis a bit angular or prism-like? (as seems from the picture). How many angles, if so.

Comment: I'll go back to the tree to get more close up pictures

Comment: After more research I now think it is [Casuarina obesa - Swamp Sheoak](http://www.avongro.com.au/Webpages/documents/GAWASwampSheoak.pdf) but will still get some more close up pictures (when it is not raining)

Comment: Those are great photos!

Comment: @AlwaysConfused - I've added a close up of the nodes / internodes - but a shame the whole tree has fallen in the river!

Comment: Ahh I'm so sorry I forgot to mention close-up the apical portion (which this photograph do not incluse) of these stem axes. *Casuarina* sp. male inflorescence occur at tip portions; such as in [*Casuarina equisetifolia*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Casuarina_equisetifolia_leaves.jpg) and your mentioned species [*C. obesa*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Casuarina_obesa_(6102944352).jpg). Was there something that looks like [earbuds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_swab)?  Unfortunate the tree is falling in water.

Comment: But still this photo would help. Did you have a  twig sample of it?

Comment: [This](http://melbourneurbanforestvisual.com.au/) Melbourne tree map website may help you.

Comment: My tree was just a bit off that map. Yes, I do have a twig sample. I'll photograph some more tonight.

Comment: From the [ridges and furrows](http://bugs.bio.usyd.edu.au/learning/resources/plant_form_function1/images/plants_extreme/xerophytes/CarrelphotoX09.jpg) on its stem it seems quite like *Casuarina* sp. **But otherwise, from its branching and greenness of older (seemingly woody) twig portions, it looks far different**. I've never seen it but I'll continue trying. I can't even conclude about its systematic position. However, from last updates it seems there are some yellow coloured flowers or anthers or cones but it is very hazy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Native cherry, Cherry ballart or Cypress cherryn belongs to the sandalwood family of plants.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exocarpos_cupressiformis

Comment: I think your right. All the pictures on [this page of Exocarpos cupressiformis](http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=sp&name=Exocarpos~cupressiformis) match all my photos

Answer (score 4):

I did some research following the latest answer on species of *Exocarpos*. I believe it is *Exocarpus cupressiformis* as well.

You can refer to this Australian website for a key to determine the actual species of *Exocarpos* : http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=gn&name=Exocarpos#4

Also, as I researched, I found other *Exocarpos* species to mismatch with your images, except for two; *Exocarpos cupressiformis* and *Exocarpos strictus*. One mismatch of *E. strictus* was with the way flowers were arranged in your last few pictures.

Find below the pictures of flowers of *E. cupressiformis* (First) and *E. strictus*:
[image]
[image]

You can see that *E. strcitus* has the flowers blooming on stem edges and not at all on tips. In contrast, your images show flowers clustering at tips just like *E.cupressiformis*.

Comment: You are most welcome.